# Parse store current user in class

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am tryign to store the current username in the class and having such a tough time.
This is only part of the code

```
String usernameNewbet = currentUser.getUsername().toString();

                bets.put("EndDate", endDate);
                bets.put("EndTime", actualTimeString);
                bets.put("Player_Pointer", usernameNewbet);
```

But when I am trying to save I am getting this error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably created a `Pointer` column named "Player_Pointer" and tried inserting a `String` into it. When saving pointers in Parse, you're supposed to provide the actual object, in this case the `User` itself, to the field, and not the objectId.

In your case, change this:

```
String usernameNewbet = currentUser.getUsername().toString();
bets.put("Player_Pointer", usernameNewbet);
```

To this:

```
bets.put("Player_Pointer", currentUser);
```

Comment: Yes, then it is giving me the actual pointer to the users table but that is not what I am looking for. But I think I understand what u meant..

Comment: You can instead change the column type to String and use your existing code

Comment: Ok, I got it resolved! I deleted the columns as they are created as pointer columns the firsttime. And when I added again they created as new columns.